# How to customize ttk.Checkbutton colors?

Tags: python, tkinter, styles, ttk

I am looking for a way to change the background color (and the active color) of the tickbox of the ttk.Checkbutton [image]

Optimally, the background color of the box should match the background's color?

What is the command to modify this in the `style.configure()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to change the colors of the tickbox using the options `indicatorbackground` and `indicatorforeground`.

```
style.configure("TCheckbutton", indicatorbackground="black", indicatorforeground="white",
                background="black", foreground="white")
```

To change the active colors, you need to use `style.map()` instead of `style.configure()`.

```
style.map("TCheckbutton", background=[("active", "darkgrey")])
```

Note that with some themes (e.g. OSX and Windows default themes), the above commands do not produce any effect because the tickbox is created with an image. If this is the case, you can change the theme to use, for instance, "alt" or "clam", with  `style.theme_use("clam")`.

If you want to keep using a theme that does not allow to change the tickbox color, you can use your own tickbox images instead:

```
# create custom tickbox element
img_unticked_box = tk.PhotoImage(file="/path/to/unticked_box_image")
img_ticked_box = tk.PhotoImage(file="/path/to/ticked_box_image")
style.element_create("tickbox", "image", img_unticked_box, ("selected", img_ticked_box))
# replace the checkbutton indicator with the custom tickbox in the Checkbutton's layout
style.layout(
    "TCheckbutton", 
    [('Checkbutton.padding',
      {'sticky': 'nswe',
       'children': [('Checkbutton.tickbox', {'side': 'left', 'sticky':     ''}),
    ('Checkbutton.focus',
         {'side': 'left',
          'sticky': 'w',
      'children': [('Checkbutton.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})]
)
```

I obtained the layout of the `Checkbutton` with `style.layout("TCheckbutton")` and then replaced `'Checkbutton.indicator'` by `'Checkbutton.tickbox'`.