How to emulate another theme's style with a tkinter ttk.Checkbutton
I'm using mostly-vanilla Debian Bookworm and Python 3.11.2.
I like the default "themed" tkinter (ttk) widgets except for the checkbutton. If I change from the 'default' theme to the 'alt' theme (in tkinter), the checkbutton looks great but the other widgets look antique :)
default theme:

'alt' theme:

I want to modify the ttk.Checkbutton() so that it looks like it would using the 'alt' theme. I see how to use ttk.Style() for things like background color, font size, etc, but I don't know how to change the graphic from a filled square to a checkmark.
Any way to do this? I'm willing to tweak tkinter from within python, but I'm hoping that I don't need to learn tcl/tk...
Code used:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.StringVar(value="Entry")
pb = ttk.Button(root, text="Button")
ent = ttk.Entry(root, textvar=text)
cb1 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Check1")
cb2 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Check2")
pb.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5)
ent.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=5)
cb1.grid(column=0, row=2)
cb2.grid(column=0, row=3)
cb1.state(['selected', '!alternate'])
cb2.state(['!alternate'])
root.mainloop()

Add the following for the 'alt' theme:
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('alt')


Maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72827704/how-to-customize-ttk-checkbutton-colors

@СергейКох, Thank you! The last part of that answer is exactly what I needed, and couldn't find :)

To customize ttk.Checkbutton  to appear as it does in the 'alt' theme while keeping other widgets in the default teme, you can try selectively configuring the style of the ttk.Checkbutton without switching the entire theme. for ex:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# configure the 'Checkbutton' style for 'alt' theme
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')

# create a new style for 'Checkbutton based on 'alt' theme
style.configure("Custom.TCheckbutton", indicatorcolor="#000000",
                indicatorrelief="groove", indicatordiameter=10, padding=5)

# Apply the style 
text = tk.StringVar(value="Entry")
pb = ttk.Button(root, text="Button")
ent = ttk.Entry(root, textvar=text)
cb1 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Check1", style="Custom.TCheckbutton")
cb2 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Check2", style="Custom.TCheckbutton")

# Layout
pb.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5)
ent.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=5)
cb1.grid(column=0, row=2)
cb2.grid(column=0, row=3)

root.mainloop()


Hope this helps.

Thank you! But this doesn't change the graphic from a filled square to a checkmark. Do you know how to change that aspect of the appearance?
